# Want to add field values in specific column comparing to other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is the snapshot of the two columns I'm working on. 
What I want to do is that, fill the blank fields of 'country_code' column with the UN alpha-3 codes.
The code of the country must match with the ccTLD (country code Top Level Domain).

Example - for the field value in 'domain' column, let's say the domain is "www.xyz.it". So, if the corresponding field value of 'country_code' column is empty then it must get filled with UN alpha-3 country code associated with that very ccTLD, which here is "ITA" for ".it"

This tis the code that I've tried to parse the domains in 'domain' column

```
for dom in df['domain']:
if type(dom) is float:
    continue
else:
    ccTLD = dom.split('.')[-1]
    print(ccTLD)
```

The place where I'm struck is, not figuring out a way to fill the empty fields of 'Country_code' column in coding. I'm looking forward to Python code to help me!

By the way here is the file where the UN alpha-3 codes are given with their ccTLD

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk2Gv.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: You shouldn't post images of data or code. Instead you should paste it with `code-formatting`

Comment: I'm not being able to upload the image of the sample data but let me give you a gist:-

| domain          | country_code|
------------------------------------------
|www.123.us   | USA |
|www.angel.br | BRA|
|www.abc.cn   | CAN |
|www.def.it      |          |
|www.ea.uk     | GBR |
|www.123.nz   |          |
|www.123.in    |          |
|www.123.ae   |          |
|www.456.af    | AFG  |

So, I want to fill these missing fields with their UN alpha-3 country codes for every ccTLD other than generic ccTLD (com, gov, edu, nic, org, ...)

Comment: I've added the image. the image opens when you click on the "enter image description here"

Comment: 1) Question has nothing to do with `scikit-learn`, `jupyter-notebook`, or `sklearn-pandas` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed) 2) please post your sample data as **text**, *in* your question and not in the comments space